# Command specified with 'ExecStopPost' is not executed with systemd-run

Tags: systemd

I'm playing around systemd and want to explore the possibility of running a cleanup script after another script (that is running as a systemd service) exits abruptly. To begin with, I ran the below command to try out how `ExecStopPost` works.

```
systemd-run --quiet --wait --pty --collect --user -p ExecStopPost="echo After" echo Before
```

I'm expecting the command to have the below output

```
Before

After
```

But after printing `Before` (That's when the main process finishes), the screen freezes and it doesn't execute the command specified in `ExecStopPost`.

Do I need to pass any other property to `systemd-run` in order to make `ExecStopPost` work, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like the tty is not functional at this step, so you shouldn't rely on it (`ExecStopPost="sh -c 'echo After > /tmp/execstoppost.out'"` doesn't block). Now to *prove* that... I didn't find any relevant documentation.

Comment: I'm not yet convinced that `systemd-run` would initiate a "stop" action. It seems to me that it executes the given command (and waits for that command to exit).